# Using argv and strcmp at C

Tags: c, argv, strcmp

Im having some problem to use the strcmp function. Everytime I run this code, it just print the ERROR mensage, even if i use the correct argument at prompt.

```
if (strcmp(argv[1], "\?") == 0) {
    ajudaPrompt();
}else {
    printf ("ERROR.\n\n");
    system("pause");
}
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: What is the "correct argument"?

Comment: program.exe \?.
The "\?" one. When i use \?, it should exec the function ajudaPrompt();

Comment: What platform uses backslash \ to denote command-line arguments? Are you sure it should not actually be the forward slash / ?

Comment: Yes, and now it works fine. The user should type "program.exe \?" at cmd if he need help, so it shows help mensage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `\` character is used to begin an escape code in C strings.  For example, `\n` denotes a newline.

Since `\?` is not a valid escape code, the backslash character is ignored.  So the resulting string in the code is actually `"?"`.

If you want you string to contain a literal backslash, use two backslashes.

```
if (strcmp(argv[1], "\\?") == 0) {
```

Comment: @Marcos Glad I could help.  Feel free to [accept this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.